# How to fix my redundant jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I cannot figure out how to make my jQuery a little less redundant. Basically what I'm trying to do is allow users to click on a thumbnail (or button) of the video they want to watch, have that video play in the player, add an active class to the thumbnail and change the title of the video depending on which one is being played. I have accomplished most of this, however, my code is way too overcrowded and will be tough to edit in the future.

```
<!— here is the thumbnail playlist that can start a video on click —>

<ul id="playlist">
 <li class="active"> <a href="show1.mp4" id="item1" onclick="changeTitle('episode 1')"><img src="img.png" alt="" /></a></li>
 <li> <a href=“show2.mp4" id="item2" onclick="changeTitle('episode 2')"><img src="img.png” alt="" /></a> </li>
 <li> <a href=“show3.mp4" id="item3” onclick="changeTitle('episode 3’)”><img src="img.png" alt="" /></a> </li>
 <li> <a href=“show4.mp4" id="item4” onclick="changeTitle('episode 4’)”><img src="img.png" alt="" /></a> </li>
 <li> <a href=“show5.mp4" id="item5” onclick="changeTitle('episode 5’)”><img src="img.png" alt="" /></a> </li>
</ul>


<! — show title that needs to changed depending on the video clicked —>

<h3 id="show-title">Now playing episode 1</h3>


<!— here are buttons that can also start the video on click —>

<button id="video-1" onclick="changeTitle('episode 1')”>Watch Now</button>
<button id="video-2” onclick="changeTitle('episode 2’)”>Watch Now</button>
<button id="video-3” onclick="changeTitle('episode 3’)”>Watch Now</button>
<button id="video-4” onclick="changeTitle('episode 4’)”>Watch Now</button>
<button id="video-5” onclick="changeTitle('episode 5’)”>Watch Now</button>


<!— using this to activate video on click —>

$( "#video-1, #item1" ).click(function() {
      flowplayer().play(“show1.mp4");
});

$( "#video-2, #item2" ).click(function() {
      flowplayer().play(“show2.mp4");
});

$( "#video-3, #item3" ).click(function() {
      flowplayer().play(“show3.mp4");
});

$( "#video-4, #item4" ).click(function() {
      flowplayer().play(“show4.mp4");
});

$( "#video-5, #item5" ).click(function() {
      flowplayer().play(“show5.mp4");
});


<!— using this to change the title according to which video was clicked —>

function changeTitle(name)
  {
     document.getElementById("show-title").innerHTML = "Now playing " + name;
  }



<!— using this to add and remove active class to thumbnails in playlist —>

$('#playlist li').on('click', function(){
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: You call this overcrowded? I am sure I have done way more overcrowded codes than this, and still managed well.

Comment: Well it's not that it's too overcrowded yet, but it will be once there are 20 videos or more that need to be played using this code format. I'm just looking for a more efficient way to code this.

Comment: how are you filling the data ? by json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take use of class (so you can assign a single event) and data attributes to store information about which video to play.

```
<!— here is the thumbnail playlist that can start a video on click —>

<ul id="playlist">
 <li class="active"> <a href="show1.mp4" id="item1" class="item" data-video="show1.mp4" data-name="episode 1"><img src="img.png" alt="" /></a></li>
 <li> <a href=“show2.mp4" id="item2"  class="item" data-video="show2.mp4" data-name="episode 2"><img src="img.png” alt="" /></a> </li>
</ul>


<! — show title that needs to changed depending on the video clicked —>

<h3 id="show-title">Now playing episode 1</h3>


<!— here are buttons that can also start the video on click —>

<button id="video-1"  class="video-button" data-video="show1.mp4" data-name="episode 1">Watch Now</button>
<button id="video-2”  class="video-button" data-video="show2.mp4" data-name="episode 2">Watch Now</button>
```

**JS**

```
<!— using this to activate video on click —>

$( ".video-button, .item" ).click(function() {
    var video=$(this).attr('data-video'),
        name=  $(this).attr('data-name')
    flowplayer().play(video);
    document.getElementById("show-title").innerHTML = "Now playing " + name;
});



<!— using this to add and remove active class to thumbnails in playlist —>

$('#playlist li').on('click', function(){
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

You can also delegate events to avoid it to assign for each element

```
$( "#yourContentWrapper" ).on('click','.video-button, .item'function() {
    var video=$(this).attr('data-video'),
        name=  $(this).attr('data-name')
    flowplayer().play(video);
    document.getElementById("show-title").innerHTML = "Now playing " + name;
});
```

Comment: You mean from my answer , or felix's answer?

Comment: If you replace the `data-name` attribute with the `title` attribute the show title will be displayed to the user when they hover their mouse over either the anchor or button.

Comment: Thanks @TAS Showing title make sense.

Comment: @SudhanshuYadav, It's not working right. The video doesn't play in the player when clicked on thumbnails, instead it opens up in a new window. Also, the buttons don't work. Here is the link to the page using your code. http://colorspectrumtv.com/testing/testing.html .If you could take a look at it and help me out that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @SudhanshuYadav, UPDATE: Changed position of the scripts. The buttons work now, but the title doesn't change though and the thumbnails still open the video up in another window as opposed to the player.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do like this:

```
$('id^="video-", id^="item"').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
    flowplayer().play("show" + id + ".mp4");
});
```

Comment: One more thing i want to include in it, add `changeTitle('episode '+id)` and remove the event from the DOM elements `onclick="changeTitle('episode 2')"`

Comment: The main limitation with this solution is that there is an upper limit of ten possible movies: show0.mp4, show1.mp4, ..., show9.

Comment: @TAS You're correct, if that's the case we can use a simple regex `$(this).attr('id').match(/\d+$/)` to do the job

Comment: @Felix Yes, that would be better. But still the prefix will always be limited to 'show'; ie show123.mp4.

Comment: @TAS I think that is the requirement from OP's question, isn't it?